# How to set action event for JavaFX Exception Dialog's button

Tags: java, javafx

I am now doing a simple sudoku game by JavaFX. And now I met some difficulty on dialog. I had create two scene, the menu scene contain only "new game" and "continue" button, main scene contain sudoku game. In the main scene I had created a check button to check if the gamer's answer is correct, where if it is incorrect then show a dialog like this [img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bHIt.png) and when it's correct,it might like this [img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DWw0.png).

Then I found that CONFIRMATION ALERT is very similar. All I need to change is to the button's text and it's action,while when click retry to back to game scene and click quit to back to the main scene.

Now I know how to set action for the button in alert box, but i had some new question for that, I have no idea how to call the `ventHandler<ActionEvent>` in the statement.

Here is my code for two alert box

(source code from https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

```
Alert right = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
right.setTitle("Checking Result");
right.setHeaderText(null);
right.setContentText("Your answer is correct. Would you like to start
again");
ButtonType restart = new ButtonType("Restart");
ButtonType quit = new ButtonType("Quit");
right.getButtonTypes().setAll(restart, quit);

Alert wrong = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
wrong.setTitle("Checking Result");
wrong.setHeaderText(null);
wrong.setContentText("Your answer is incorrect. Would you like to try 
again");
ButtonType retry = new ButtonType("Retry");
wrong.getButtonTypes().setAll(retry, quit);
```

the code for actions

```
Optional<ButtonType> result = right.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == quit) {
stage.setScene(main_frame);
}else if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == 
restart) {// call the actionevent clears}

Optional<ButtonType> result = wrong.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == quit) {
stage.setScene(main_frame);
}else if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == 
retry) {// call the actionevent clears}
```

The code for eventhandler

```
final EventHandler<ActionEvent> clears = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        if (digging_array[i][j] == 1) {
                            sudoku[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(final_Array[i][j]));
                        } else {
                            sudoku[i][j].setText("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: *Then I found that CONFIRMATION ALERT is very similar* - what is `CONFIRMATION ALERT` - where is the code for this?

Comment: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: I could not reproduce this on a Windows 10 machine. Also include your JRE and OS details in your question.

Comment: I am using Java8 on Win10 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did change the button type correctly regarding the `right` alert. Your last line does not change the buttons for the `wrong` alert. Replacing `right` with `wrong` will target the correct alert and thus change its buttons.

Checking which button was pressed can be done in multiple ways. Extract from the official documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html):

Option 1: The 'traditional' approach

```
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
    formatSystem();
}
```

Option 2: The traditional + Optional approach

```
alert.showAndWait().ifPresent(response -> {
    if (response == ButtonType.OK) {
        formatSystem();
    }
});
```

Option 3: The fully lambda approach

```
alert.showAndWait()
     .filter(response -> response == ButtonType.OK)
     .ifPresent(response -> formatSystem());
```

instead of using `ButtonType.OK` you need to use your custom buttons.

### EDIT

In your example you have to modify the code like this:

```
void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (digging_array[i][j] == 1) {
                sudoku[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(final_Array[i][j]));
            } else {
                sudoku[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}

Optional<ButtonType> result = right.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == quit) {
    stage.setScene(main_frame);
} else if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == restart) {
    clear()
}

Optional<ButtonType> result = wrong.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == quit) {
    stage.setScene(main_frame);
} else if(result.isPresent() && result.get() == retry) {
    clear()
}
```

Comment: Sadly, i still have no idea about how to call a event handler in that. Actually that is the stuff bothers me

Comment: I think you are a little confused. There is no need for an event handler when working with alerts. All you have to do is create a method and call that method.
In your example you have to do the following: (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

In the linked tutorial, there is an example on how to set custom actions (I shortened it a bit):

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");

ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
    // ... user chose "One"
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```

You can get the result (what the user clicked) via `result.get()` and check, which button was pressed (buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel, ...).

When the user presses "One", you can now do something in the first body of the if statement.

In your code you are missing the `showAndWait()` call. If for example the user was right, you should do:

```
Observable<ButtonType> rightResult = right.showAndWait();

if (rightResult.isPresent()) {
    if (rightResult.get() == restart) { //because "restart" is the variable name for your custom button type
         // some action, method call, ...
    } else { // In this case "quit"

    }
}
```

Note, this is probably not the most elegant way (double if-statement) to do it. @Others feel free to edit my answer and put in a better way to do it.

Comment: You're comparing a `Optional` to a `ButtonType` instance which always returns `false`. You need to retrieve the value from the optional: `if (rightResult.orElse(quit) == restart)`...

Comment: Good point, you are right. You can also call `rightResult.get()` and call `rightResult.isPresent()` before, just to be save. Thanks for pointing out, edited my answer.

Comment: Actually,I had tried to use '.showAndWait();' but it will kind of overcast all my scene   at first place, when I start to run it will show the alert fist then my menu scene

Comment: How about call a event handler in it? How to achieve that?

Comment: I think, just like Mustapha wrote, you do not need an event handler for this. The dialog appears because the programs runs through your code right up to the `.showAndWait()` call. You should put the code for the dialogs into an extra method, which gets called when the user presses some kind of "Check my Result" button. Then the dialogs only appear, when the user wants to check if he is correct.